# Display random jpg in imageview

Tags: android, imageview

I have a bunch of images in my raw folder with names ranging from 1.jpg to 100.jpg. I want to generate a random number between 1 - 100 and then based on the number generated display the corresponding image in an imageview e.g. random number 5 so display 5.jpg.

How can I do this? Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
oncreate(){

1- initialize your imageView say imgView.
2- generate a random number between 1 to 100, say random.
3- make sure you have all those 100 images in your res/drawable folder.

4- get the res ID related to the random by using following code:

    int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(random), "drawable", context.getPackageName());

5- imgView.setImageResource(id);

}
```

Hope this helps you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
  Random random = new Random();

  // The +1 because nextInt(100) delivers between 0-99
  int drawableNumber = random.nextInt(100) +1;

  String drawableName = recourceNum + ".jpg";

  yourImageView.setImageDrawable(getRecource().getDrawable(getRecources().getIdentifier(drawableName, "res/drawable", yourPackageName);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private static int getRandomInteger(int aStart, int aEnd) {
    long range = (long) aEnd - (long) aStart + 1;
    long fraction = (long) (range * new Random().nextDouble());
    int randomNumber = (int) (fraction + aStart);
    return randomNumber;
}
```